# pkg_resources.get_distribution() returns diffrent path to location when pyproject.toml is used

Tags: python, setup.py, python-packaging, pyproject.toml, pkg-resources

I have a python project that is installed via `setup.py`.
I usually install it as editable install:

`py -3 -m pip install -e <path_to_my_project>`

before I added `pyproject.toml`, execution of such an instruction:

```
import pkg_resources
pkg_resources.get_distribution('my-project')`
```

returned:

`my-project 0.0.0 (<path_to_my_project>)`

After adding `pyproject.toml` (empty), the execution of this instruction looks like this:

`my-project 0.0.0 (c:\users\<user>\appdata\local\programs\python\python310-32\lib\site-packages)`

What should be added to `pyproject.toml` to have backward compatibility?

My `setup.py` looks as followS:

```
from setuptools import setup, find_packages

setup(
    name='my-project',
    packages=find_packages(where='src'),
    package_dir={"": "src"},
)
```

I tried https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/reference/build-system/pyproject-toml/#fallback-behaviour

Comment: Is your pip up to date? Maybe you are using a pip that does not have support for "editable" installations with `pyproject.toml` ([PEP 660](https://peps.python.org/pep-0660/)). I believe it was added in ["_pip v21.3_" released on 2021-10-11](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/news/#v21-3).

Comment: yes, pip is upgraded

Comment: But is the project installed as editable or not? What is the actual problem?

Comment: When empy `pyproject.toml` is added to the project and the project is installed as editable (`py -3 -m pip install -e .`), then `pkg_resources.get_distribution` returns the path to the site packages instead of <path_to_my_project>.

Comment: Maybe a bug... Maybe you could ask here: https://github.com/pypa/setuptools/issues -- Or you could try with `importlib.metadata` instead of `pkg_resources`.